# Assigning response to new object poins to the same referance

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am fairly new in Angular and have a problem connected with assigning a json response from server to new instantiated object.

I have a class MyClass

```
export class MyClass {
Id: number
}

obj: MyClass;
myService.fetch().subscribe(a=>obj=a);
```

The problem is, that response from server has five properties and when I assign this response to my object it got them all although this object has only one property "Id".

I am printing both this objects to console by

```
myService.fetch().subscribe(a=>{
obj=a
console.log(a);
console.log(obj);
}});
```

And I receive two the same objects. Why this happens? Shouldn't I be notified that assignment cannot be done, because there are missing properties on class MyClass?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `a` ? If it isn't typed properly, Typescript can't detect the missmatch.

> Shouldn't I be notified that assignment cannot be done, because there are missing properties on class MyClass?

No, there are *additional properties* on `a`. They don't change the way how your code does interact with `obk`, so there is no problem with assigning an object with more properties to a type with less. Typescript has duck typing after all (if something has an `Id` it is a `MyClass`).

Comment: I can't agree that obj: MyClass is only labeled statement because when I write:
this.obj = false; IDE complains that false is not assignable to type MyClass.

Comment: @justme oh, thats inside a class? That wasn't clear from the question

Comment: Yes, it is inside